# Is there an equivalent of extract method of MySQL in Apache Derby?

Tags: derby

Is there an equivalent of [**extract**](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_extract.asp) method of MySQL in Apache Derby? Or doesn't Derby support it?

Comment: What does that method do? Can you provide a reference or link? What similar techniques have you tried in Derby? etc. Remember, the more effort you put into your question, the more likely you are to get a valuable answer...

Comment: extract method retrieves the unit out of a date. See here - http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_extract.asp . This is implemented in MySQL. I was using MySQL earlier and was trying to use Derby for a Hobby Project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derby does not have an exact equivalent of extract.

[It has](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj29026.html):

- [Second](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsecondfunc.html)
- [Minute](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefminutefunc.html)
- [Hour](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefhourfunc.html)
- [Day](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefdayfunc.html)
- [Month](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefmonthfunc.html)
- [Year](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefyearfunc.html)

But you can always [write your own functions](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefcreatefunctionstatement.html):

```
CREATE FUNCTION TO_DEGREES(RADIANS DOUBLE) RETURNS DOUBLE
PARAMETER STYLE JAVA NO SQL LANGUAGE JAVA
EXTERNAL NAME 'java.lang.Math.toDegrees'
```

See also:

- Overview: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/DerbySQLroutines
- DayOfWeekExample: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/db-derby-user/200510.mbox/%3C43418926.6010407@sun.com%3E